# Issues installing gazebo7

Tags: installation, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. As per http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions I need Gazebo7. I want to install the latest LTS version (which I believe is 7.16.0-1).

The link to the instructions for installing Gazebo on Ubuntu does not work. Try it: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install

The installer download link also doesn't work. Go to http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_b&tut=guided_b1 scroll to "installation for Ubuntu" and click on "link to the installer". didn't work for me.

No worries. I'll just download the software and off I go, right? I wish. On this page (http://gazebosim.org/distributions/gazebo/releases/) there are 7 files that are "Gazebo7 ... 7.16.0-1 (docs, dbg, plugin-base, libgazebo7, common, and gazebo7), and every one depends on the other. I tried installing each one over and over in different orders, but I keep getting unmet dependencies.

Installing Gazebo from source makes my head spin (I'm not a programmer, and this is too much for me: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source&cat=install)

Gazebo is so cool, and I need the latest Gazebo7 version. What do I need to do to install Gazebo7? Thanks for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24385/issues-installing-gazebo7/) by [TorontoRoboticsClub](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/22877/torontoroboticsclub/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`gazebo7`is an official package in Ubuntu Xenial 16.04. The [tutorial says that it should be automatically installed](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions#Kinetic) when you need to install ROS packages. So a simple `apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full` should just work.

If you want to get the latest `gazebo7` then you can follow [these instructions to proceed step by step](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_ubuntu&ver=7.0#Alternativeinstallation:step-by-step). Basically add the OSRF repository together with the key.

**(edited after comment)**
Back to the original question of getting the latest `gazebo7` version after installing `ros-kinetic-desktop-full` and got `7.0.0`: steps should be the same as detailed in the step by step tutorial basically add the osrfoundation.org repository and run `apt-get install gazebo7`. That should give you the following output:

```
root@f8f9dfa4bc91:/# apt-get install gazebo7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gazebo7-common gazebo7-plugin-base libbullet-dev libbulletsoftbody2.83.6 libgazebo7 libgazebo7-dev
Suggested packages:
  gazebo7-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbullet-dev libbulletsoftbody2.83.6
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gazebo7 gazebo7-common gazebo7-plugin-base libgazebo7 libgazebo7-dev
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libbulletsoftbody2.83.6 amd64 2.83.6+dfsg-3 [104 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libbullet-dev amd64 2.83.6+dfsg-3 [243 kB]    
Get:3 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable xenial/main amd64 gazebo7 amd64 7.16.0-1~xenial [2338 kB]
Get:4 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable xenial/main amd64 libgazebo7-dev amd64 7.16.0-1~xenial [615 kB]
Get:5 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable xenial/main amd64 gazebo7-common all 7.16.0-1~xenial [40.1 MB]
Get:6 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable xenial/main amd64 gazebo7-plugin-base amd64 7.16.0-1~xenial [945 kB]                                              
Get:7 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable xenial/main amd64 libgazebo7 amd64 7.16.0-1~xenial [6390 kB]
```

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2020-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TorontoRoboticsClub](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/22877/torontoroboticsclub/) on 2020-02-10**:
When I installed Kinetic, the version that came with it was 7.0, and I jumped through hoops to get 7.16 working (which is where this question came from). first I uninstalled gazebo7*, then I installed gazebo7-common for 7.16, then I did run the `apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full` and everything worked. The only problem is the 30 other commands that may have done something useful. My conclusions is it's possible to delete 7.0 and reinstall 7.16. Good luck....